# Get value of custom column from Lookup Field in View - Client Side Rendering

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-online, client-side-rendering

I'm wondering if is possible use the Id of the `Lookup` Field for obtain a custom column created in the `list`.

Example:

I have two lists called *Books* and *Authors.*

Here, *Authors* has a `LookUp` field to *Books* and *Books* has a Column called *NumberOfPages* (which is NOT part of the View that I’m using `CSR`).

The `View` has all columns of the *Authors* List and only this two columns of the *Books* (Id and Title) *the default ones for a `Lookup`.*

*What I tried:*

- Update the `List Settings` of the *Authors* List for edit the *NumberOfPages* Column and in the section called *Add a column to show each of these additional fields* I checked the *NumberOfPages* field.

However, is NOT a option have visible this column *NumberOfPages*, but I need the info that this column contains, there’s a way to accomplish it?

A *possible* solution is add the *NumberOfPages* column in the `View` and after in the [`OnPostRender`](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/620110/SharePoint-Client-Side-Rendering-List-Views) method *dissapear* this column from the `View`.

The approach what I'm trying to get explained in a cleaner way is [detailed in this answer](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/129359/35471) and with some adjustments with the [code provided here](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/Client-side-rendering-code-2625e5e3) I'm trying:

1. Get the value of the *NumberOfPages* column.
2. Save the obtained value in a `var` variable.
3. After make some calculations *which aren't part of my question*, remove the column *NumberOfPages* from the `View`.

The following code this that I get at the moment editing the code provided in the links metioned before for try hide the *NumberOfPages* column, but the column stills visible in the `View`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
(function () {

var coloringFieldContext = {};
coloringFieldContext.Templates = {};

coloringFieldContext.OnPostRender = hideFields;

//coloringFieldContext.Templates.Fields = {
//     "FieldName": { "View": coloringFieldTemplate }
//};

    SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(coloringFieldContext    );
})();

//function coloringFieldTemplate(ctx) {

//    var currentFieldValue = ctx.CurrentItem[ctx.CurrentFieldSchema.Name];
//    var currentRefferedFieldValue = ctx.CurrentItem["NumberOfPages"];

//   if (currentRefferedFieldValue === "Test") {
//       return "<span style='background: red;'>" + currentFieldValue + "    </span>";
//}
// else {
//   return "<span style='background: green;'>" + currentFieldValue + "    </span>";
 // }
//}

function hideFields(ctx) 
{ 
    var cell = $("div [name='NumberOfPages']").closest('th'); 
    var cellIndex = cell[0].cellIndex + 1; 

    $('td:nth-child(' + cellIndex + ')').hide(); 
    $('th:nth-child(' + cellIndex + ')').hide(); 
}
</script>
```

*Code added inside `Web-Page` which has a `Script Editor` component instead in a `script` file separately and a `View` with the columns described at the beginning of the question.*

---

*I'm still reading and trying to understand this "new logic" of rendering info in SharePoint and I read some blogs for get informed, but there's not info about what I'm trying to get.*