# Hide more than one list column with JSlink

Tags: jslink, client-side-rendering

I am using CSR against two columns, both of which I need to hide from the list view.

I have used this example to successfully hide one:

```
function hideFields(ctx) 
{ 
var cell = $("div [name='myField']").closest('th'); 
var cellIndex = cell[0].cellIndex + 1; 

$('td:nth-child(' + cellIndex + ')').hide(); 
$('th:nth-child(' + cellIndex + ')').hide(); 
}
```

but I also need to hide another column and am struggling to do so - I've tried writing a separate function with new variable names but this doesn't work. Can I add a further column into the existing hideFields function ?

Comment: hi, can you not apply them the same class- then hide the elements of this class?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this one, you just need to replace the values in the array in line 2:

```
OnPostRender: function(ctx) {
    ["col1", "col2"].forEach(function(name) {
        var header = document.querySelectorAll("[displayname=" + name + "]")[0].parentNode;
        var index = [].slice.call(header.parentNode.children).indexOf(header) + 1;
        header.style.display = "none";
        for (var i = 0, cells = document.querySelectorAll("td:nth-child(" + index + ")"); i < cells.length; i++) {
            cells[i].style.display = "none";
        }
    });
}
```

(jQuery is not necessary for this script)

Comment: Solved my problems. Thanks! If you have empty spaces or special characters in you display names just add an apostrophe like this: "[displayname='" + name + "']"

Answer (score 1):

Our farm didn't like the Vanilla JS of Daniel's answer so I ported it over to jQuery

```
["col1", "col2"].forEach(function(name) {   
        var header = jQuery("[displayname='" + name + "']").parent();

        var siblings = header.parent().children();
        var index = siblings.index(header) + 1;

        header.hide();

        jQuery("td:nth-child(" + index + ")").hide();

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that both answers are useful and work well. The only remark that I would like to review in both codes is to avoid using "**displayname**" from DOM. Using the "name" selector is much better. It will help to avoid encoding mistakes and matching wrong field name, especially if you using non-latin international names for your fields.
For expamle:
`var header = document.querySelectorAll("[name=" + name + "]")[0].parentNode;` for Daniel's code
and
`var header = jQuery("[name='" + name + "']").parent();` for the example.