# Issues with trying to hide a column with JS Link in multiple webparts on the same page

Tags: jslink, client-side-rendering

I found a solution in the below post to hiding columns using JS link. However, I have multiple webparts on a page with different views of the same list and it is only hiding the columns in the first webpart. I want it to hide the columns in all webparts.

Any thoughts on why this doesn't work?

FWIW, I have other js in the same file to update display values in the same list (different columns) that is working across all webparts as expected.

[Hide more than one list column with JSlink](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/192994/hide-more-than-one-list-column-with-jslink)

```
OnPostRender: function(ctx) {
    ["col1", "col2"].forEach(function(name) {
        var header = document.querySelectorAll("[displayname=" + name + "]") 
                     [0].parentNode;
        var index = [].slice.call(header.parentNode.children).indexOf(header) + 1;
                    header.style.display = "none";
        for (var i = 0, cells = document.querySelectorAll("td:nth-child(" + 
            index + ")"); i < cells.length; i++) {
            cells[i].style.display = "none";
        }
    });
}
```